# Spring boot mock application properties value while testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I am trying to write unit test of method which is in the image but I put a breakpoint and checked the application.properties value. It was 0 but i set 5 before. After I added this code to the my test class but is not working still.

@SpringBootTest(properties = {"maxPlayerCount = 5"})

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is your `maxPlayerCount` variable getting set? I assume you're using Spring Boot's `@ConfigurationProperties` support. Can you share the code that you think should result in the value of `maxPlayerCount` property being applied to your variable?

Comment: in application.properties file i have this line: maxPlayerCount = 5

Comment: That's not enough on its own for a variable in your code named `maxPlayerCount` to be set with its value. You need to be using something like `@ConfigurationProperties` or `@Value` for that to happen.